# Excel question on addition with integers and string values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to fill in the cells below ROW1 with adding 2 onto the last number. Example below:

```
        ColA    ColB    ColC
ROW1    G385    G384     G288
ROW2
ROW3
```

Desired result

```
        ColA    ColB    ColC
ROW1    G385    G384     G288
ROW2    G387    G386     G290
ROW3    G389    G388     G292
```

Right now if I drag and drop the cells in row1, the results will increase by 1, I need them to increase by 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you fill two rows and drag down --> Fill as Series it will know to step by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula I think you're looking for is:

`= "G" & Value( right( B2, len(B2)-1)) + 2`

This takes "G" and adds it to the beginning of the solution. The math take the value of all the characters right of the G and adds 2.